# Load custom html & css on a webpage?

Tags: css, html

I don't really know what you call this, so I don't know what to type in Google to further research this. I was wondering how you delete certain elements of a webpage as it loads. A lot of userscripts use this. I want to know how do it. I think some webpages are just way to cluttered and I'm tired of editing the source code to clean it up. So how would I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete elements after it's loaded. Some browsers cannot remove element until whole source code is loaded. Than google for removeNode. Usage is parentElement.removeNode(removingElement). ParentElement and removingElement are referencies to elements, NOT ther IDs.

If on server side, than you have to use some preg functions to match and replace the code, or better, use XML functions to parse code and delete some elements (note: this require 100% valid code).

Comment: If I was to edit the source code then refresh the page, the edits I made would disappear. Would there be a way to save those edits? And obviously have and option to restore it (doing this all via client-side).

Comment: If you will place these in javascript file (talking on user-side removing) and load this javascript file to the page, than elements will be removed everytime. Or... Are you talking about removing elements via browser inspector? Because sounds me like that...

Comment: I'm kind of confused on what you just said... I am on Firefox, when I right-click it will say "inspect element" there, I can remove certain features of the webpage currently on (i.e. div classes and id's and such). How would I go about loading the customized html instead of it going back to normal when I refresh the page?

Comment: ehm... You really cannot save anything from inspector... Inspector is mainly for developers, there is no posibility to manage with that any source code for forever.

Answer (score 0):

How can a script ever determine what is useful for you or not?its a subjective issue

Do you want every code on a new line uncluttered?for example do you want [this](http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/demos/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/scripts/jquery.inview.js) type code where everthing is on a new line instead of something like  [this](http://www.labnol.org/wp/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/hY5hDsMgCIUv1OqOsis4yyILglOM8fbTttn-rQkJvPB4fC3ZllZkT3WDYl-j3hVyP9vS9r0XVmC1GiAOFxBE5Gl2dUNZE7kOeblZcg8WMsVnTPrTEbj-TZoKn30mnqMpQbJ6GVBXDAepSRlU-z2IytXF98fO-QE.js.pagespeed.jm.9OroOFUjMY.js)

Update:
Here is a trick

copy paste the whole code to jsfiddle.and save it every time you change it

Comment: I'm not talking about a script that determines what is useful or not. I'm wanting something that I can edit the source code (via inspect element) and it will still be customized when I refresh the page.

Comment: copy paste the whole to to jsfiddle?and then edit it and save it every time u change it?

Answer (score 0):

For firefox, you can use greasemonkey https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ an here's how to use greasemonkey for chrome on Windows http://mashable.com/2008/12/15/google-chrome-greasemonkey-scripts/